# Switching from Mockito to JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, jmockit

I used to rely on Mockito until today I have a final class with some static methods so I've to switched to JMockit. I knew nothing about it before so the question is: how can I apply the similar logic from Mockito to JMockit?

```
public final class ServiceData extends BaseData {

    private List<Data> data;

    public ServiceData(List<Data> data) {
         this.data = data;
         // something else
    }

    public static Container getContainer() {
         return super.getContainer();
    }

    public Data getDataAt(Index index) {
         return super.getContainer().get(index);
    }

}
```

The test written in Mockito looks like:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ServiceData mockServiceData = mock(ServiceData.class);
    Data mockData = mock(Data.class);
    // only stubbing some of the methods
    Container mockContainer = spy(Container.class);
    doReturn(something).when(mockContainer.someMethod());
    when(mockServiceData.getContainer()).thenReturn(mockContainer);
    when(mockServiceData.getDataAt(any(Index.class)).thenReturn(mockData);

    // some assertions
}
```

This won't work since Mockito cannot mock final classes nor static methods (getContainer)
So how can I write the same logic in JMockit? Thanks.

Comment: Usually when Mockito prevents something, it's a good indicator of a design smell. Why does `getDataAt` rely on a static method from the parent class? Why are you trying to mock `ServiceData` in the first place?

Comment: Good point. But essentially this is not a real class but a fake one I wrote down intentionally only for this question. The class obviously doesn't follow some design rules. The purpose is to get the ideas of how to migrate the code. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is the JMockit equivalent for the example test:

```
@Test
public void test(
    @Mocked final ServiceData mockServiceData, @Mocked final Data mockData,
    @Mocked final Container mockContainer)
{
    // only stubbing some of the methods
    new Expectations(mockContainer) {{
        mockContainer.someMethod(); result = "something";
        mockServiceData.getContainer(); result = mockContainer;
        mockServiceData.getDataAt((Index) any); result = mockData;
    }};

    // some assertions
}
```

To mock `static` methods the syntax is the same, except that you would write `ServiceData.getContainer(); result = mockContainer;` instead.